# Eigen: matrix to quaternion and back have different result

Tags: matrix, eigen, quaternions

I use Eigen library to covert matrix to quaternion, but when I turn one of the matrix to quaternion and burn it back, it turn out to be another matrix which is identity matrix. The rotation matrix I use was decomposed from a transform matrix.

```
    Eigen::Matrix3f R3d = R.topLeftCorner<3,3>();
    *Rquat = R3d;

    R3d = (*Rquat).normalized().toRotationMatrix();
```

What may cause this problem?
[This is the matrix before change to quaternion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0smtg.png)

and [This is the matrix when I turn it back form the quaternion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT88T.png)

Comment: The matrix you are passing is a reflection, so you can't get a valid quaternion out of it. Nevertheless, what version of Eigen are you using?

Comment: I am using Eigen 3

Comment: So version 3.0? That has been deprecated for a while ...

Comment: Be sure that source rotation matrix is realy rotation only matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked the implementation of [Eigen's matrix to quaternion conversion](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/2b969e50885e26f0ca909ebb2b0263cd9c649bd6/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h#Quaternion.h-760). It is based on "Quaternion Calculus and Fast Animation", by Ken Shoemake.

And as one can see when analyzing the source, this assumes that the matrix is indeed a rotation matrix (or close to one). In fact all symmetric matrices with `M.trace()>0` will result in a (scaled) identity quaternion. If you expect anything else for invalid rotation matrices, you need to implement your own conversion method.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been suggested by previous answers and comments, unit quaternions can only represent 3D rotation matrices.

For a matrix to be a rotation matrix, it has to lie in SO(3), [the special orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#SO(n)), which is defined by :

[image: so3]

So you need to check if the matrix times its transpose equals identity and if its determinant equals one (and not minus one, or else it only lies in the [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group), and not in its sub-group, the special orthogonal).

At this time, the [Eigen function](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h) used to create a quaternion from a matrix does not check if the passed matrix is indeed a rotation matrix. A fix or a warning may be needed because this can lead to unexpected behaviours, as you described.

I have found myself in the same position because I tried to form a quaternion from a change of basis matrix (formed by three basis vectors), and it only worked when the said basis was a direct one. If not direct, the transformation from this basis to the [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) (and vice-versa) is not a rotation.