# How to convert Transformation matrix to Quaternion?

Tags: c++, eigen, quaternions, euler-angles

Hi I have obtained the Transformation Matrix which looks like this

> transformation matrix:

```
-0.999702 -0.00155921  -0.0243653     0.62702
        0    0.997959  -0.0638626   -0.287402
-0.0244151   0.0638436    0.997661  -0.0212277
       0           0           0           1
```

I would like to convert the Transformation matrix to rotation matrix and then to Quaternion. I know that the rotation matrix can be converted to Quaternion in C++ using `getQuaternionFromRotationMatrix`. But my problem is how to transform the Transformation matrix I have into rotation one.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: The rotation matrix is the upper-left 3x3 matrix assuming there are only translations and rotations but no shearing nor scaling.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Eigen: convert Matrix3d rotation to Quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21761909/7478597), [SO: Eigen: convert rotation matrix to quaternion then back getting completely different matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46967752/7478597), [SO: Eigen: matrix to quaternion and back have different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896041/eigen-matrix-to-quaternion-and-back-have-different-result). More: [google "eigen getQuaternionFromRotationMatrix"](https://www.google.com/search?q=eigen+getQuaternionFromRotationMatrix) ;-)

Comment: ok. Thanks so I just use the upper left 3x3 matrix of the transformation matrix and then getQuaternionFromRotationMatrix right?

Comment: Yes. This will work if the matrix was built exclusively from rotations and translations (regardless of how many of them).

Comment: I have done it but gon an Error.      Eigen::Matrix3f Rotation_matrix = transformationMatrix.topLeftCorner<3,3>();     auto Quaternion = Rotation_matrix.getQuaternionFromRotationMatrix(); Error is Eigen::Matrix3f {aka class Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3>}’ has no member named ‘getQuaternionFromRotationMatrix’  Any help?

Comment: Just write `Eigen::Quaternionf quaternion(transformationMatrix.topLeftCorner<3,3>());` If that does not work, post a [mre].